# Unix: If/then statement is always false

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

This if/then statement in Unix *always* puts me in the else statement. I am using Bash.

```
name="Don"
if [ "$name" == "Don" ]; then
  echo "Hi Don!"
else 
  echo "You are not Don. You are: $name"
fi
```

This is my first Unix shell script, so I'm sure it's something obvious. I've checked against the style guide and other if/then examples, but don't see anything wrong:  http://www.dreamsyssoft.com/unix-shell-scripting/ifelse-tutorial.php.

Comment: Can you show (a) a copy of the output when it is failing, and (b) the output of `bash -x yourscript.sh`?

Comment: Figured it out, it was konsolebox's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're in a POSIX shell don't use `==`. Instead use `=`. `==` is specific to Bash.

```
name="Don"
if [ "$name" = "Don" ]; then
  echo "Hi Don!"
else 
  echo "You are not Don. You are: $name"
fi
```

Comment: I seem to be in Bash. I ran `ps -p $$` and it returns `bash` among other things.

Comment: Nevermind, stupid mistake I am in POSIX, thanks! (Needs 4 minutes to accept)

Answer (score 3):

I executed your script and it jus tworked as expected.

If this it the full code snipped, did you propably forget to call the bash?
I am asking this because when executing the snipped with "sh", it behaves exectly as you said as this is just partial valid for sh.

So I think you missed this:

```
#!/bin/bash
name="Don"
if [ "$name" == "Don" ]; then
  echo "Hi Don!"
else 
  echo "You are not Don. You are: $name"
fi
```

Comment: This is actually just a portion of the script, the rest executes fine

Comment: okay, but with the line I added above you are securing that your script will be run as a bash.script, for which your code was fine.

Answer (score 0):

There was only one thing wrong in your original code: the line that reads

```
echo "Hi Don!"
```

The shell is trying to interpret the special character `!`
Try putting this line single quotes example:

```
echo 'Hi Don!'
```